# I want to move from one form to another old already form programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, forms

I have created two forms in a Windows Forms application using C#. I just want to move from one form to the other. I don't want to open a new form.

I created a `LinkLabel`, an `OnClickEventHandler` and in that handler I want to move to already created form programmatically.

Is there any property of `LinkLabel` so I can set name or address of other form? So that on click it can automatically take me there?

Comment: Just call `yourForm.Activate()`

Comment: There is nothing like activate()

Comment: I say `Form.Activate()` method? there is no built in feature for this with `LinkLabel`

Comment: there is form2.activeForm() but it says it can not be invoked as a method

Comment: You're looking at static members, am talking about instance method. You need to get the instance of showing form then call `yourForm.Activate()`. Is that clear?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel THANKS and Formobj.show();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you open the second form in a similar way

```
 Form2 f = new Form2();
 f.Show();
```

If this is the case, then you could save the reference to the second form in a global class level variable and use that reference when you need to show again the second form

```
private Form2 theSecondForm = null;
....

// Open the second form...
theSecondForm = new Form2();
theSecondForm.Show();
```

When you need to switch to the second form

```
// Check if the second form is still available
if(theSecondForm != null && !theSecondForm.IsDisposed)
    theSecondForm.Show();
else
{
    theSecondForm = new Form2();
    theSecondForm.Show();
}
```

Notice, that before calling the second form show method is better to check if the variable is still valid and point to a real instance of the second form. You could also wire to Form Close event to be notified if the user closes the second form

```
theSecondForm = new Form2();
theSecondForm.Show();
theSecondForm.FormClosed += ClosingSecondForm;

private void ClosingSecondForm(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
   // Set the global variable to null... this prevent to call a closed form
   theSecondForm = null;
}
```

Comment: can i open the form if its name is stored in some variable